# wget on ftpes:// (explicit FTPS)

Tags: 19.10, ftp, wget

When I run the following command:

```
wget --user=anonymous ftpes://x.x.x.x:x/FTP/image.bin.gz
```

It returns that `ftpes` is not supported.

Is there a missing package to be installed to support `ftpes` in `wget`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/542826/not-able-to-wget-to-ftp-server) helps

Comment: @dragosht it doesn't speak about ftpes in wget, so i don't think that could help.

Comment: I understand FTPES is FTP whereby the encrypted connection is made explicitly, instead of implicitly. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312403/download-all-files-via-ftp-with-explicit-tls-ssl-encryption) may help.

Comment: Please confirm your wget is created with ssl. ftpes = ftp + tls/ssl and not all wget's used have been created with ssl. http://www.hep.by/gnu/wget/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html explains this. Ah @jos beat me :) You need `wget` version 1.18 or higher. So do a `wget --version` to check what you use.

Comment: @Jos feel free to make an answer on AU.

Comment: @Rinzwind GNU Wget 1.20.3 compilé sur linux-gnu.

-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls 
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/openssl

Comment: I tried every option in --secure-protocol and then added --no-check-certificate but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312403/download-all-files-via-ftp-with-explicit-tls-ssl-encryption),  the following has been confirmed by the OP to work, provided the `wget` version is 1.18 or higher:

```
wget --secure-protocol=auto --no-proxy \
     --no-passive-ftp --ftp-user=XXXXX --ftp-password=YYYYY \
     --no-check-certificate ftps://ZZZZZZZZ.com:21
```

or the `curl` equivalent:

```
curl ftp://myuser:mypassword@x.x.x.x:x/FTP/image.bin.gz -k \ 
    --ftp-ssl --output image.bin.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jos : Yes that works !

```
wget --secure-protocol=auto --no-proxy --no-passive-ftp --ftp-user=myuser --ftp-password=mypassword --no-check-certificate ftps://x.x.x.x:x/FTP/image.bin.gz
```

or with curl:

```
curl ftp://myuser:mypassword@x.x.x.x:x/FTP/image.bin.gz -k --ftp-ssl --output image.bin.gz
```

Comment: Thanks. I will edit my answer to include the actual commands that worked for you. If you feel my answer is satisfactory, please mark the question as answered by ticking the mark next to it.